# BLE device- same code and same firmware works well with iphone SE and works not as good in iphone 7 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am working with ibeacon. I created an application for tracking devices. But I am facing a problem with the application. The app works well in the terminated state for iPhone SE whereas it is not working (in the locked state) for iPhone 7+.In the unlocked state it is working for 7+ also but still it is very slow compared to iPhone SE. Is there any specific reason for this problem. If it can be solved, what could be the possible solution to this problem.

I am really helpless and clueless about this issue.Please do help me and assist me with your knowledge Sir. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When an iOS app is in the background, it relies on two different mechanisms to detect beacons:

1. Hardware filters.  These are byte  patterns stored on the Bluetooth chip that alert the OS when a BLE advertising packet is received that matches your beacon region.  This mechanism is very fast and delivers results within a second, but it is a limited resource.  Once all slots are full, it will no longer work. There is no documentation about the number of slots available on each iPhone model, but experiments suggest the number is ~30.
2. Software scans.  A full BLE scan is performed to find all beacons even if they are not stored in a hardware filter.  In the foreground with ranging active, software scans are constant.  In the background they are periodic to save battery, so detections based on software scans are much slower.  The rate is undocumented, but experiments suggest software scans are performed every ~10 minutes in the background in the typical phone state.  An additiona softwarel scan is also performed when the screen is unlocked.

The problem description is consistent with hardware filters (1) not working on the iPhone 7+.  This may not be a problem with the phone model, it could be a problem with the specific device, or more likely the software state on the phone.  A typical cause is the installation of multiple beacon apps that use up all the slots.  Each beacon app can register up to 20 beacon regions for monitoring, so just two apps could use up all the slots!.  The first apps to run and register slots may hold them forever.

A few troubleshooting tips:

1. Uninstall any other apps you think may. be detecting beacons, then re-install yours.
2. Restart your device.

If the above does not help, you may have a hardware problem with your device.  Try another iPhone 7+ to see if you can reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my case I tested the app with two iphone 7+ and an iPhone SE. So I am pretty sure that it is not because of that particular device.I also tested the app with an iPhone 8+ and it is also slow. And surprisingly the SE has a lot of beacon scanner apps and than 7+.

Comment: But you say the 7+ "is very slow compared to iPhone SE", so why do you not agree it is device-specific (or device configuration-specific)?  The problem I describe is not precisely a matter of how many beacon apps there are on the phone, but how many regions are registered by these apps and **which apps registered them first**.  Whether or not this is the cause of your problem, this is absolutely a cause of these symptoms.  As part of troubleshooting, you must eliminate this potential cause